# Why is carbonylation added as a fixed modification in mass spectrometry peptide analysis?

Tags: molecular-biology, biochemistry, mass-spectrometry

When using mass spectrometry analysis software we use carbonylation as a fixed modification. What is the significance of this modification and why doesn't it change?

Comment: which MS method are you using ?

Comment: We are using  dda on a high  res lc- ms